# Music21: get track index of a note

Tags: python, midi, music21, mido

I have a [multi-track midi file](http://www.jsbach.net/midi/1079-02.mid) that I'm reading with music21:

```
import music21

f = music21.midi.MidiFile()
f.open('1079-02.mid')
f.read()
stream = music21.midi.translate.midiFileToStream(f).flat
note_filter = music21.stream.filters.ClassFilter('Note')
for n in stream.recurse().addFilter(note_filter):
  offset = n.offset # offset from song start in beats
  note = n.pitch # letter of the note, e.g. C4, F5
  midi_note = n.pitch.midi # midi number of the pitch, e.g. 60, 72
  duration = n.duration # duration of the note in beats
  instrument = n.activeSite.getInstrument() # instrument voice
```

I'd like to figure out which track each note in this stream belongs to. E.g. when I open the file in GarageBand, the notes are organized into tracks:

[image]

In `mido`, each `MidiFile` has a `tracks` attribute that contains one list of notes for each track.

Is there a way to get the same with music21? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41019546/152016 ?

Comment: I hadn't seen that! I'd like to keep the stream method though because I want to merge all tracks into one stream so the time attribute is absolute rather than relative though. `f.tracks` exists and contains one entry for each track. But then the time is based on relative offsets within the given track...

Comment: https://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleMidiTranslate.html#music21.midi.translate.midiTrackToStream Can't you just change the tracks' data and call this method in the parent midi object ?

Comment: Hmm, how do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The music tracks are parsed into separate `stream.Part` objects, so you can just walk through the parts of the `stream.Score` that you produced if you avoid flattening it (here, I've just produced a stream with `converter.parse()`:

```
s = converter.parse('1079-02.mid')
for part in s.parts:
    for note in part.recurse().notes:
       print("I WAS IN PART ", part)
```

or look up the containing part:

```
s = converter.parse('1079-02.mid')
for note in s.recurse().notes:
    part = note.sites.getObjByClass('Part')
    print("I WAS IN PART ", part)
```

I doubt you really need to flatten anything. Good luck!